# Sbt Native Packager Debian installation uses root user instead of daemon user

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I am creating a debian package of my Scala Play 2.3.8 application with the sbt native packager (`"com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0"`). The startscripts that are being generated use a custom user to start and stop the app which is exactly as intended.
The problem is, that the installation with `dpkg -i package.deb` seems to start the app directly after the installation as root user. The `/var/run/neeedo-app/running.pid` is then owned by the root user and all further stop or start attempts fail because this file cant be overwritten by the daemon user.

This is my build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV

name := """neeedo-api"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

maintainer in Debian := "neeedo-team <neeedo@neeedo.com>"

packageSummary in Debian := "neeedo api application"

serverLoading in Debian := SystemV

packageDescription := "neeedo api application"

daemonUser in Linux := neeedo-api

daemonGroup in Linux := neeedo-api
```

I am running the dpkg install command also with the neeedo-app user. I don't understand why the running.pid file is created by the root user after installation. If I delete the file manually with sudo and use the start/stop script afterswords everything works fine...

Edit (Answer):
It seems like starting the app as root(with dpkg) is not really an issue. The running.pid file is in a directory that is owned by the app user. Therefore it can edit and delete the pid file.

My application is using environment variables in its config and when you run the start script with sudo as root user you have different environment variables. This led to the fact the the app couldn't start and unfortunately no error reporting was visible (I have to investigate further to see why because normally this should be reported).

Comment: Yes I did. See the edited part in the Question...

Comment: The issue I have is running `sudo dpkg -i deb_pack` creates dirs owned by root, however the start script `/etc/init/myproject.conf` runs service as custom user, thus pid file cannot be created due to permission issues. Any clues?

Comment: The /var/run/app_name directory should be owned by the daemonUser. Maybe you can find a solution in this github issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/560#issuecomment-96399032

Comment: It is owned by user howerver it is empty.

Comment: What steps do yo take to create/install/run deb package?

Comment: Create: `./sbt debian:packageBin`, Install: `sudo dpkg -i --force-confold neeedo-api_1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb` and it runs from itself because of the SystemV Config... You might wanna doublecheck if anything else is blocking the start of your application. For example you can run the generated startscript in /usr/share/appname/bin on your own and see if this throws an error